# Get a new access_token from IdentityServer4 when validated Google Id Token from SPA

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am creating IdentityServer4 auth with ASP.NET Identity, for React SPA and an ASP.NET Core Web API with policy-based authorization.

[Take a look at this flow diagram as I am not yet able to embed images directly into the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZQt9.jpg)

So basically what I have done till now,

1. React SPA will have "Sign in with Google" ("react-google-login" lib) on successful Google login
2. Received response with "tokenObj" which contains **IdToken** and other stuff
3. POST request, using **Id token** and some extra claims field, from **React SPA** to the **IdentityServer4** endpoint
4. Validated **IdToken** from IdentityServer4 controller endpoint using Google client library method Google.Apis.Auth.GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync
5. On successful IdToken validation Create/Get the user using ASP.NET Identity UserManager methods and,
6. Also, the custom claim which was passed in the POST request is added for that user into DB

**What I want to do now**,

7. Getting an "access_token" from the IdentityServer4, to pass it into that POST request's successful response.

Note: Don't want to pass Google provided access_token to the React SPA. Want
to pass an IdentityServer4 issued **access_token** to the SPA. And Access token should contain that custom claim while decoded, further to process policy-based
authorization in another API.
I also knew about ProfileService is used to pass the custom claims inside the access token issued by IdentityServer4, so ProfileService I have implemented.

So the question is mainly focused on how to pass the new **access_token** issued by **IdentityServer4** after validating users using Google IdToken.

#### Minimal working example

```cs
  public class ExternalLoginModel
     {
        public string IdToken { get; set; }
        public string UserRole { get; set; }
     }
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ExternalAuthController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("google")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateGoogleSignin(ExternalLoginModel externalLoginModel)
        {
            Payload payload;
            var provider = "google";
            try
            {
                // currently no need to validate
                var validationSettings = new ValidationSettings
                { Audience = new[] { "YOUR_CLIENT_ID" } };
                payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(
                    externalLoginModel.IdToken, validationSettings);
                 // create custom claims and store claims for the user found from Google IdToken
                 // storing custom claims passed in request if user is created.
                var userRole = externalLoginModel.UserRole;
                var user = await GetOrCreateExternalLoginUser("google", 
                                                                    payload.Subject,
                                                                    payload.Email,
                                                                    userRole);

                return Ok(new
                {
                    access_token = "want_to_give_identity_server4_issued_access_token"
                });
            }
            catch
            {
                // Invalid token
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
}
```

Comment: I have taken reference from this https://github.com/mickeysden/dotnet-core-react-oauth-example/blob/master/backend/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L32
But in this project, as JwtSecurityToken() is used in a similar way I want the access token from the IdentityServer4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make this more complicated than it has to be.

I think the better approach is to let your SPA application ask your backend (ASP.NET Identity) to ask IdentityServer to authenticate the user. Then using external authentication, IdentityServer will ask the user to authenticate with Google.

By doing this, IdentityServer and Google will talk directly to each other. After authentication you will get the tokens back from IdentityServer and sent back to ASP.NET Identity. Using these tokens a proper session cookie can be issued to your SPA application.

This is a more secure approach to avoid the SPA application to deal with this.

To get the external authentication in place, here's a few starting points:

- [Exchanging external tokens from Facebook, Google and Twitter](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/community.html?highlight=external#exchanging-external-tokens-from-facebook-google-and-twitter)
- [Sign-in with External Identity Providers](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html)

Besides that I think the question might need a bit more clarification? perhaps a picture of your setup could help.

Regarding your picture, you should not go from React directly to Google, instead you go via IdentityServer and then Google, like in this picture:

[image]

The react and Google should never interact directly. IdentityServer shields your application from Google.

Comment: Basically, I have two SPAs, one for ClientAdmin and other for EndUsers.When any user registers themselves from respective SPA using Google "Sign-in", I want to store user's custom claims like "user_role" e.g. "clientAdmin" OR "paidUser". And in the response want an access_token from the IdentityServer4 with these custom claims of the particular SPA user. So any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for, External providers samples link you provided, I have already gone through and as in their solution, they are using custom grant validators. But it didn't resolve my one problem that passing the custom claims from the ReactSPA to IdentityServer4. So do we have any way to pass custom claims and storing claims to DB and getting them into access token issued by IdentityServer4, while using Custom Grant like e.g. 'external'?

Comment: I clarified my answer above, hope that makes this answer acceptable

Comment: I was learning/researching the flow u provided. In this flow, I am able to call or redirect to IdentityServer endpoint "ExternalLoginChallenge" from my SPA using location.href.. please correct me if this is the right way? to perform Challenge. And then, I got redirected to Google sign-in screen, on a successful sign-in, got a callback to IdentityServer "ExternalLoginCallback" GET endpoint with "returnUrl" pointing to my SPA, now able to create/find user using ASP NET Identity. So from here, the question is how will I get IdentityServer access token and get redirected to my SPA?

Comment: No, you never call the ExternalController directly (sure you can) but normally its a link that is generated in the Accounts\Login view. Then you will know that you get all the details correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to perform the below steps in order to get customs claims for an user:-

1. Add the custom claims to the list of IdentityResource.
2. set up the claims against the user.
3. Add the claims in the list of allowed scopes against the client for
   which token has to be issued.
4. Once you have acquired an access token from identity server using
   the token you can then call the user Info endpoint `GET /connect/userinfo` to get the list
   of claims set up for the user.

Comment: Steps to store and getting the custom claims are already performed for ResourceOwnerPassword grant type and got the custom claims directly inside the IdentityServer4 provided access token using the implementation of IProfileService.
So basically I need a way to get the access token with my custom claims from the IdentityServer4, for external providers like Google, Facebook.

Comment: I am sorry i am a bit confused , Please correct me if  i am wrong - So the requirement is the user's custom claim should be included in the access token generated by the identity server ?

Comment: I have added a diagram link to make it a clearer situation. And made some changes into the description of the scenario. Please, Can you have a look?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong - upon successful sign-in from google you are passing id_token along with customuserroleclaim to identity server ,you are then storing the claim in the sql db against the user and now you would like to pass the role claim in the access token upon successful validation of id_token by the identity server?

Comment: Upon successful sign-in from google, passing id_token along with customuserroleclaim to IdentityServer, on successful validation of id_token by the identity server from google token endpoint, receives the user info, now stores the claim in the MSSQL db against the user using ASP NET Identity. And now would like to pass the access token provided by IdentityServer for that user to my SPA?? so that I can authorize that user on another Web API by some policy

Comment: This access token is needed, because how can I get the access token for an external login user which does not even have a password so that I can somehow follow Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) flow to get Access Token from "connect/token" endpoint of Identity Server